# VirtualHost fails with multiple interfaces

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

I have instance with multiple interfaces and I am trying to configure Apache with IP-based virtual hosting to serve multiple websites, but for some reason it just returns the main document root.

I followed [this](https://www.internetstaff.com/multiple-ec2-network-interfaces-on-red-hat-centos-7/) tutorial to get multiple interfaces working.

**What is wrong:** The website should show `/var/www/mydomain/index.html`, but instead it shows `/var/www/html/index.html`.

**What I have tried:** Using *:80 in VirtualHost, which works but the goal is to have multiple VirtualHosts each from different IP/interface. Removing port from VirtualHost: Doesn't do anything. Changing `Listen 80` to `Listen 92.168.1.231:80`, which fails with `Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 92.168.1.231:80`. This is worrying and I haven't found any explanation what is happening. There is nothing else listening the port and if I just listen all 80 ports it works fine.

Info on my config:

/sbin/ifconfig

> eth0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>          inet 192.168.1.231  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>          inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fee7:b528  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>          ether fa:16:3e:e7:b5:28  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>          RX packets 8812  bytes 6501811 (6.2 MiB)
>          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>          TX packets 3884  bytes 331594 (323.8 KiB)
>          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> eth1: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>          inet 192.168.1.232  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>          inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fea1:e658  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>          ether fa:16:3e:a1:e6:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>          RX packets 10623  bytes 788238 (769.7 KiB)
>          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>          TX packets 5290  bytes 1647702 (1.5 MiB)
>          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> eth2: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>          inet 192.168.1.233  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>          inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fead:8432  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>          ether fa:16:3e:ad:84:32  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>          RX packets 6520  bytes 396490 (387.1 KiB)
>          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>          TX packets 51  bytes 4973 (4.8 KiB)
>          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> eth3: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>          inet 192.168.1.234  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>          inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe4a:8dc7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>          ether fa:16:3e:4a:8d:c7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>          RX packets 33438  bytes 3106902 (2.9 MiB)
>          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>          TX packets 26161  bytes 16106821 (15.3 MiB)
>          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
>          inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>          inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
>          loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
>          RX packets 1992  bytes 199852 (195.1 KiB)
>          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>          TX packets 1992  bytes 199852 (195.1 KiB)
>          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

sudo httpd -S

> VirtualHost configuration:
>   92.168.1.231:80        www.mydomain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/sites.conf:1)
>   ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
>   Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
>   Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
>   Mutex proxy: using_defaults
>   Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
>   Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default
>   Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
>   Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
>   Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
>   Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
>   Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
>   PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
>   Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
>   Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
>   User: name="apache" id=48
>   Group: name="apache" id=48

cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/sites.conf

```
<VirtualHost 92.168.1.231:80>  
    ServerName www.mydomain.com  
    ServerAlias mydomain.com  
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydomain/"  
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/mydomain/error_log"  
    TransferLog "/var/log/httpd/mydomain/access_log"  
</VirtualHost>
```

sudo netstat -pntl (when having Listen 80 in httpd.conf and Apache running)

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)  
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1191/memcached  

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd  

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1221/sshd  

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2090/master  

tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      1386/mysqld  

tcp6       0      0 ::1:11211               :::*                    LISTEN      1191/memcached  

tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd  

tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      8094/httpd  

tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1221/sshd  

tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      2090/master
```

httpd.conf is pretty much vanilla except changing admin email, removing auto-indices from main document root and setting server name.

Comment: I wonder if the reason it won't bind to the specific IP is because it is already bound to `0.0.0.0` which includes the more specific one too. Could you check that?
What is your `netstat -pntl` output?

Comment: You were trying to (listen and) create a vhost on `92.168.1.231` but your machine does not have that address; it has (among others) `192.168.1.231`. 92 and 192 are different.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Welp... That would explain it.... No idea how I didn't notice that xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have `/etc/hosts` configured right, but fixing that didn't help.
I switched from IP based virtual hosts to domain based and it got fixed magically.
Don't really know why but it works.

Answer (score 1):

In the main server config you should have:

```
Listen 80
```

This instructs apache to listen on all interfaces (and thus on all IPs). Only change it, if you do not want apache to listen on all interfaces/IPs.

Your VHosts should be configured as follows:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.231:80>
  ServerName mydomain1.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain1
  ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.232:80>
  ServerName mydomain2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain2
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Also check that your local dns server or `/etc/hosts` file is pointing to the correct IP address.